# What is ‘emotional capture’ and how does it manifest?

Tags: emotion, attention

A quick [internet search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22emotional%20capture%22%20research&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) seems to result in a number of research papers (and similar) that discuss specific studies/experiments regarding the phenomenon, but virtually nothing seems to focus on defining and discussing emotional capture in a more broad/general sense (e.g. there is no Wikipedia article for the term). Since it seems unlikely there are going to be any authoritative sources for this, I would just like to know how you best understand the concept and maybe a basic example or two of how it occurs in everyday life — thank you!